# Sorting only subcategories second level alphabetical order

Tags: category-tree

i am aboslut new to programming with magento. I have a cms page where i want only the second level of one topcategory shown in alphabetical order.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$parentCategoryId = 125;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();


?>



<?php 

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    echo '<ul>';
    //echo '<a style="font-weight: bold" href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
    $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();

    foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
    {
          $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
          $_categories[$_sub_category->getName()] = $sub_subCatid;
          ksort($_categories);
          echo $_categories[$_sub_category->getName()];
          **if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
              echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
           }**

     }
     echo '</ul>';

  }
}
?>
```

How can i sort the it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 125)
    ->joinUrlRewrite()
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addNameToResult()
    ->addOrderField('name');

    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thx it works great